# Looking for a way to calculate 2 of 3 input fields in realtime using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple app and would like to have three inputs displayed. It will be a form to calculate market capitalization/share price/shares available. The formula for this is `{shares-available * share-price = market capitalization}`. I would like to have dummy text in each input and allow the user to add any two values and have the third value calculated automatically. I understand the HTML and CSS portion, but I have been trying a ton of different things with the JavaScript and keep running into walls that I hadn't anticipated and having to start over from scratch(never really getting all that far anyway).

My HTML:

```
<div class="container center">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-100">
            <input data-ctp type="text" id="ctp" name="firstname" placeholder="Coin/Token Price">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-100">

            <input data-cs type="text" id="cs" name="lastname" placeholder="Circulating Supply">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-100">
            <input data-mcap type="text" id="mcap" name="lastname" placeholder="Market Cap">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you are looking for is something that takes 2 values from input field A & B and solve them for a value C?
Below I'll give you something similar just for you to look at it, play around with it and use the knowledge to create exactly what you are looking for.

HTML:

```
<!-- field A -->
<input type="number" id="ctp" placeholder="Coin/Token Price" />

<!-- field B -->
<input type="number" id="cs" placeholder="Circulating Supply" />

<!-- field C, after entering value A & B we will have our answer here -->
<input type="number" id="mcap" placeholder="Market Cap" disabled />
```

My example will use JQuery to handle the JS part.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //below we create variable names for element selection
     var cpt = document.querySelector('#ctp');
     var cs = document.querySelector('#cs');
     var mcap = document.querySelector('#mcap');
     /*then we have 3 variables that will hold value A, B & C
     var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

     /*then we'll have an event listener that captures data when user input 
     values in the first 2 fields*/
     $(cpt).on('keydown',function(){
         /*this means that when a key is pressed inside the first field we take 
         whatever value is entered */
         a = $(this).val();
         //below we run a function that tests if both fields now have values
         testFields();
     });
     /*below we have an event listener just like the one above for value B
     $(cs).on('keydown',function(){
         /*this means that when a key is pressed inside the second field we take 
         whatever value is entered */
         b = $(this).val();
         //below we run a function that tests if both fields now have values
         testFields();
     });
     /*the function that tests if value A and B are provided are are higher 
     than 0 or not containing whitespaces, if both these conditions are true, we 
     calculate and return value C 
     , if not we wait for the user to input usable values*/
     function testFields(){
         if((a > 0 && b > 0) || (a !== '' && b !== '')){
             /*if value a and b are greater than 0, we calculate c, else we do 
             nothing*/
             c = a * b;
             /*once we have the value for C, we use the element selector 
             variable to display the value to the 3rd input field*/
             $(cmap).val(c);
         }else{
             /*if one or both values are less than 0 or blank we do nothing*/
             return false;
         }
     }
});
```

Here's a summary. We have 3 input fields, the first 2 accepts numerical values and the last one is a readonly field which means the user won't be able to input anything there. Then we create variables we can use to get values from input field A & B and set value for input C. We wait for user to input anything in field A & B and we test if the inserted values are greater than 0 or not empty values and if both these conditions are true we go ahead and automatically do the calculation.

This might not be what you've expected and definitely a more complicated way of doing this but since you are new and willing to learn this will be good example and exercise. From this you can be able to fully understand what's expected and then take it from there. Maybe you'll even be able to find a nicer and shorter way of doing.

Let me know if you have any follow up question.
All the best on your project.